# How to let scanf() keep reading integer inputs unless a character is input?

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a program that reads inputs from user and determine whether the integer is Fibonacci or not.

The program should print out `num is fib` or `num is not fib` where num is a positive integer;

if the input is a non-positive number, the program should not produce any output (but it should produce an error mesage on stderr) and it should keep prompting;

if the input contains any characters, the program should not produce any output (but it should produce an error mesage on stderr) and then exit.

This is the expected results:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 is fib
2 is fib
3 is fib
4 is not fib
5 is fib
```

(keep prompting inputs)

```
1 -2 3 -4 5
1 is fib
Error: input value -2 is not positive
3 is fib
Error: input value -4 is not positive
5 is fib
```

(keep prompting inputs)

```
1-23-45
1 is fib
Error: input value -23 is not positive
Error: input value -45 is not positive
```

(keep prompting inputs)

```
12a
12 is not fib
Error: input is not a number
```

I was able to check the first input number, but when it's done, the program exits itself. How do I let the `scanf()` know when to keep reading and when to exit?

This is my code

```
int main() {
    int num, x, y, z;

    while (scanf("%d", &num) > 0) {
        if (num <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: input value %d is not positive\n", num);
            return -1;
        } else {
            x = 0;
            y = 1;
            z = x + y;
            while (z < num) {
                x = y;
                y = z;
                z = x + y;
            }
            if (z == num) {
                printf("%d is fib\n", num);
            } else {
                printf("%d is not fib\n", num);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't (yet) report on 'not a number'.

Comment: Should the program exit silently at end of file?

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, just exit once characters are involved, and send a message to stderr

Comment: @Crysishy: this is not precise: if there are offending characters such as letters, you want an error message, but if there are no characters left in the input as we hit the end of file, why should you have an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently exit the `main` function when `scanf` returns less than `1`.  If a character is present in `stdin` that does not begin a number, such as `a`, `scanf("%d", &num)` will return `0`, you will exit the program, but without a message.  You also exit with `return 0;` after the first result, which is incorrect.

You must change to logic when a number cannot be parsed and only exit silently at end of file, when `scanf` returns `EOF`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int status, num, x, y, z, exit_code = 0;

    while ((status = scanf("%d", &num)) >= 0) {
        if (status == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: input is not a number\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (num <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: input value %d is not positive\n", num);
            exit_code = 1;
            continue;
        }
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        z = x + y;
        while (z < num) {
            x = y;
            y = z;
            z = x + y;
        }
        if (z == num) {
            printf("%d is fib\n", num);
        } else {
            printf("%d is not fib\n", num);
        }
    }
    return exit_code;
}
```

Comment: When the input contains any character, like 1.1 or 1a2, the program should exit, so how do I achieve that? Also, when the input is a negative number or 0, the program should not produce any output (but it should produce an error mesage on stderr), so is "fscanf" in my original code correct?

Comment: Why "return 1" under "fprintf", I thought return value should communicates abnormal execution so it should be "return -1".  And what does "continue" mean? Does it mean go back to the bigger while loop? Sorry for so much question, because I'm very new to C  :<

Comment: when does scanf return EOF?

Comment: @Crysishy: C11 7.21.6.2: *The `fscanf` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.*  In practice, `scanf` returns `EOF` at the end of file.

Comment: @Crysishy: `return 1;` is an error code. Any non zero return value from `main` may indicate some error condition, it is system specific.  You can `return -1;` if you prefer, but under unix, exit status values are usually restricted to a small range such as `0..127`.

Comment: @Crysishy: `continue` jumps to the test expression of the closest enclosing  `while` loop. If the loop was a `for` loop, it would jump to the increment expression (third expression pert of the `for` statement), and then branch to the test expression.

Comment: I just found out a problem that if input contains any non-positive numbers like 0 or -1, the program should also return 1 to indicate "exit status". Like when I do "echo $?" immediately after the program is terminated, the result should be 1 if non-negative integers or characters are involved; the result should be 0 if all the inputs are positive integers. I know I need to return 1 at some point, but it will terminate the program as well. So how do I return 1 without having the program terminated when only non-positive integers are involved?

Comment: @Crysishy: you use a local variable `exit_code` to keep track of past errors and return that at end of file.  See the updated answer.

Comment: why "void" is added in main()? Is it necessary?

Comment: Because that's the correct prototype for `main` in the C language.  Either no arguments: `int main(void)` or command line arguments: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent.

Comment: In java, a "void" class does not require a return statement. Is this the same thing in C? Like if you add "void" then it is not necessary to return anything? But I thought there is "int" before main() so you have to return int at some point. So what's the difference between add "void" or not? Since both of them compiles and works correctly?

Comment: @Crysishy: do not confuse `void func()` which is a function taking an unspecified number of arguments returning nothing and `int func(void)`, a function taking **no** arguments and returning an `int`.

Comment: @Crysishy:  `main` ca be defined as taking no arguments or as taking an `int` and a pointer to an array of C strings terminated by a `NULL`. In both cases, `main` is defined as retuning `int`.  Defining it as `int main()` will compile but is a little bit sloppy.

Comment: Thanks a loooooooooooot, that really helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you return from all of the conditions in your program. Try the following without `return 0` in the else clause:

```
int main(){
    int num,x,y,z;

    while (scanf("%d", &num) > 0){
        if (num <= 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: input value %d is not positive\n", num);
        }
        else {
            x = 0;
            y = 1;
            z = x + y;
            while (z < num){
                x = y;
                y = z;
                z = x + y;
            }
            if (z == num){
                printf("%d is fib\n", num);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d is not fib\n", num);
            }
        }
    }
    if(feof(stdin))
        return 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: input value is not a number\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the extra `return 0;` but you still exit the loop if a letter is in the input stream.

Comment: @chqrlie: I think this is the behavior that he wants. If you look at his test case: '1 2 a b c', it only prints out one Error and exits the program.

Comment: You return after reading a negative number; shouldn't you just continue — either by simply deleting the `return -1` or by using `continue` instead?  (Using `continue` isn't as good in my opinion.)

Comment: @Pooya: in case of a letter, you indeed exit correctly, but you should also output `input is not a number`.

Comment: @chqrlie: I edited the answer to reflect that too. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Better.  The hyper-critical amongst us might note that there's a distinction between 'not a number' and EOF; to capture that, you'd save the value returned by `scanf()` into a variable and test whether the variable is 0 (not a number) or EOF (…EOF, of course…) to report the difference, if you need to notify EOF at all.

Comment: Is it correct to add "continue" under the first "fprintf"? Since I want it to keep prompting for input.   And, the program should return 1 after the second "fprintf" to indicate abnormal execution, so how do I do that?

Comment: @Crysishy: you can add continue but in this case it is not necessary because the while will continue anyway.

Comment: @Crysishy: If you are looking for returning different kind of integers for each situation you should do status checking like in the chqrlie solution and also read Jonathan comment above

Comment: If the program is terminated by "ctrl + D", it should return 0; if it is exit because input contains characters, it should return 1. In this case, how should I add after the second "fprintf"?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I'm just wondering if I do it in your way, how would it be done because your solution is neater.

Comment: And I just found out a problem that if input contains any non-positive numbers like 0 or -1, the program should also return 1 to indicate "exit status". Like when I do "echo $?" immediately after the program is terminated, the result should be 1 if non-negative integers or characters are involved; the result should be 0 if all the inputs are positive integers. I know I need to return 1 at some point, but it will terminate the program as well. So how do I return 1 without having the program terminated when only non-positive integers are involved?

Comment: @Crysishy: I edited my code. I tested on my pc and it worked fine. when you send EOF it will return 0 and 1 otherwise

Comment: if(feof(stdin)) what does this mean?

Comment: it indicates if EOF is detected from stdin so you can decide whether it was EOF or non-number that cause the while loop break